# Get Store Value using FIFO T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table that contain all of my product details. and I want to get store value by FIFO Method,

[image: All Purchases]

If my stock is 3 sql give me 9000,means (3*3000)

If my stock is 5 sql give me 15000,means (5*3000)

If my stock is 6 sql give me 17000,means  (5*3000)+(1*2000)

If my stock is 15 sql give me 36000,means  (5*3000)+(8*2000)+(2*2500)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?  Also, please remove the `MySQL` tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement FIFO in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152990/how-to-implement-fifo-in-sql)

Comment: there are too slow,I'm looking for better algorithm

Comment: this is a good article : https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/set-based-speed-phreakery-the-fifo-stock-inventory-sql-problem/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a numbers table to transform the source data into 1 row per product item and then add them up:

```
-- generate numbers 1 to 10000
;with n as (
    select top 10000
        row_number() over(order by t1.number) as n
    from
        master..spt_values t1
            cross join
        master..spt_values t2    
), x as (
-- explode source table into one price row for each item
    select
        row_number() over (order by p.[date]) rn,
        p.price
    from
        product p
            inner join
        n
            on p.amount >= n.n
) select
    sum(price)
from
    x
where
    rn <= @stock;
```

This doesn't detect `@stock` being too big. If `amount` can bigger than 10,000 you'll need to look at generating more numbers.

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1462/8)

Comment: is there any simple way? cause my source table contain 5000 rows and i need to execute this query for 12000 product