# Update transaction record with FIFO in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have an application for receiving and shipping. I am handling these 2 processes in the transaction table. While receiving the item manually giving BOE number, so all receiving record having BOE number. But while shipping out an item am not updating this BOE column. Actually I need to know this Item came from which BOE (I want to use FIFO) criteria. Now my transaction table has a lot of data. But I want to know each BOE how many item came and how many item out.

I have made query like this

```
select 
    F_lot_number, sum(INq) 'IN', sum(OUTs) 'OUT', sum(BOE) 'BOEcount' 
from 
    (select 
         F_lot_number,
         case 
            when F_Stock_Type = 'IN' then sum(F_qty) 
         end as 'INq',
         case 
            when F_Stock_Type = 'out' and  F_IsBook = '2' then sum(F_qty)  
         end as 'OUTs',
         case 
            when F_Stock_Type = 'IN' 
               then count(distinct F_BillOf_entryNumber) 
         end as 'BOE'
     from 
         T_Tra_Transaction 
     group by 
         F_lot_number, F_Stock_Type, F_IsBook) d 
group by 
    F_lot_number
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

if example

```
select 
    F_QTY, F_lot_number, F_BillOf_entryNumber 
from 
    T_Tra_Transaction 
where 
    F_lot_number = '150723A151' 
    and F_Stock_Type = 'IN'

select 
    F_QTY, F_lot_number, F_BillOf_entryNumber 
from 
    T_Tra_Transaction 
where 
    F_lot_number = '150723A151' 
    and F_Stock_Type = 'out'
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

I need to update all out status with corresponding BOE number. How can I do that? i need to updated all of my existing recordes according to that.if any help am very thank full

In my table i have `transdatetime` field also there.

i have checked other lot number..

```
select 
    F_QTY, F_lot_number, F_BillOf_entryNumber 
from 
    T_Tra_Transaction 
where 
    F_lot_number = '150919C131' 
    and F_Stock_Type = 'IN'

select 
    F_QTY, F_lot_number, F_BillOf_entryNumber 
from 
    T_Tra_Transaction 
where 
    F_lot_number = '150919C131' 
    and F_Stock_Type = 'out'
```

but am getting out put like this:
[image]

Comment: In first image its showing Lot number,IN qty,Out Qty,Boe number count

Comment: dear @marc_s..did you removed my out put images from question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement FIFO in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152990/how-to-implement-fifo-in-sql)

Comment: dear @Serg ,,my condition is not same..i want to update my all existing records,,,according to i explained?

Comment: Please add Transactions table schema. is there any datetime, timestamp o r sequenced value in this table?

Comment: The referred answer explains FIFO. You need to decide which way you need to modify your data according to FIFO results. What if 150723A151 "ins" are (10,10) and "outs" are (5,7,3) for example?

Comment: @serg 150723A151 (10,10) ..that particular lot number 10 qty came and 10 qty out

Comment: @McNets i can give you table schema if you need

Comment: Then it looks like FIFO groups are identified by `Lot number` and `qty` contrary to original FIFO which groups data just by `Lot number`.

Comment: @serg ..how i can achieve this? is there any way? any help is very appreciable..in my table i have transdatetime field also there

Comment: 150919C131 data you added contradict to what you said before, in/out lots are not the same size. You really want FIFO. Try read the topic carefully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152990/how-to-implement-fifo-in-sql

Comment: My in and out are not the same..in that case how i can update then?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that every lot is always sold with the same qty it was acquired.
So the idea is just `row_number()` ins and outs properly and update outs from corresponding ins. Not tested.

```
update tout
set F_BillOf_entryNumber = tin.F_BillOf_entryNumber 
from (
    select F_QTY, F_lot_number, F_BillOf_entryNumber 
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by F_QTY, F_lot_number order by transdatetime desc)
    from 
        T_Tra_Transaction 
    where 
        F_Stock_Type = 'out'
    ) tout
join (
    select 
        F_QTY, F_lot_number, F_BillOf_entryNumber
        , rn = row_number() over (partition by F_QTY, F_lot_number order by transdatetime desc)
    from 
        T_Tra_Transaction 
    where 
        F_Stock_Type = 'IN'
    ) tin 
    on tout.F_QTY = tin.F_QTY
       and tout.F_lot_number = tin.F_lot_number
       and tout.rn = tin.rn;
```

**EDIT**

I tested it on sample data

```
create table T_Tra_Transaction(
F_QTY int, F_lot_number int , F_BillOf_entryNumber int,
     transdatetime int, F_Stock_Type varchar(3));
insert  T_Tra_Transaction (F_QTY, F_lot_number, F_BillOf_entryNumber,transdatetime,F_Stock_Type)
values
(10,1,101,200,'IN'),
(20,1,102,201,'IN'),
(20,1,null,200,'out');
```

Comment: Invalid column name 'transdatetime'.

Comment: I take it from your comment "i have transdatetime field also there". Correct it according to your real schema.

Comment: i wan to update all out shipment lot number with corresponding BOE number

Comment: Provide sample data so we can see the problem.

Comment: sir how i can give my data to you,,,?

Comment: if you provide any mail or somthing i will send to you across

Comment: This looks like a request for a professional service. :) You can get the answer for free if you publish some samples, obfuscating or excluding sensitive data here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133739/discussion-between-user3262364-and-serg).

Comment: still confused how i can give sample data here..thatsy i asked sir,,

Comment: See edit You may provide it the same way. Change data types as needed.