# Oracle - Function vs Procedure Performance

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql

I'm putting together a package to perform some operations and return an associative array of date spans.  I had been using functions, but I started to wonder if that was the best option performance-wise, so I put together a test package to check it out:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pk_perf_test IS

  TYPE pt_rDateSpan IS RECORD
  (
    start_date DATE,
    end_date DATE
  );
  TYPE pt_aaDateTable IS TABLE OF pt_rDateSpan INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  
  FUNCTION pf_getDateTable (p_nInputParam INTEGER) RETURN pt_aaDateTable;
  PROCEDURE pp_getDateTable (p_nInputParam INTEGER, op_aaDateTable OUT pt_aaDateTable);
  PROCEDURE pp_getDateTable_NoCopy (p_nInputParam INTEGER, op_aaDateTable OUT NOCOPY pt_aaDateTable);

END pk_perf_test;
```

Each of the function/procedures just run the same query with `BULK COLLECT` into the collection using the input parameter as a bind variable. Like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pk_perf_test IS
  FUNCTION pf_getDateTable 
  (p_nInputParam INTEGER)
  RETURN pt_aaDateTable
  IS
    l_aaToRet pt_aaDateTable;
  BEGIN
    SELECT mt.start_date, mt.end_date
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_aaToRet
    FROM my_table mt
    INNER JOIN my_other_table mot ON mt.pk_col = mot.fk_col
    WHERE mt.pk_col = p_nInputParam;
    
    RETURN l_aaToRet;
  END pf_getDateTable;
  
  PROCEDURE pp_getDateTable
  (p_nInputParam INTEGER, op_aaDateTable OUT pt_aaDateTable)
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT mt.start_date, mt.end_date
    BULK COLLECT INTO op_aaDateTable
    FROM my_table mt
    INNER JOIN my_other_table mot ON mt.pk_col = mot.fk_col
    WHERE mt.pk_col = p_nInputParam;
  END pp_getDateTable;
  
  PROCEDURE pp_getDateTable_NoCopy
  (p_nInputParam INTEGER, op_aaDateTable OUT NOCOPY pt_aaDateTable)
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT mt.start_date, mt.end_date
    BULK COLLECT INTO op_aaDateTable
    FROM my_table mt
    INNER JOIN my_other_table mot ON mt.pk_col = mot.fk_col
    WHERE mt.pk_col = p_nInputParam;
  END pp_getDateTable_NoCopy;
END pk_perf_test;
```

I then wrote a short script to test these to determine performance:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_tsStartTS TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE;
  l_iFunctionTotal INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := INTERVAL '0' SECOND;
  l_iProcedureTotal INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := INTERVAL '0' SECOND;
  l_iNoCopyTotal INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := INTERVAL '0' SECOND;
  l_aaDummy pk_perf_test.pt_aaDateTable;
  l_nDummy INTEGER := 123;
  l_nCaseCount INTEGER := 0;
  
  CURSOR c_ids IS
    SELECT mt.pk_col
    FROM my_table SAMPLE (10) mt;
BEGIN
  --Priming Query Run to make sure plan is cached
  SELECT mt.start_date, mt.end_date
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_aaDummy
  FROM my_table mt
  INNER JOIN my_other_table mot ON mt.pk_col = mot.fk_col
  WHERE mt.pk_col = l_nDummy;
  
  FOR r IN c_ids LOOP
    l_nCaseCount := l_nCaseCount + 1;
    
    l_aaDummy.DELETE;
    l_tsStartTS := SYSTIMESTAMP;
    l_aaDummy := pk_perf_test.pf_getDateTable(r.pk_col);
    l_iFunctionTotal := l_iFunctionTotal + (SYSTIMESTAMP-l_tsStartTS);
    
    l_aaDummy.DELETE;
    l_tsStartTS := SYSTIMESTAMP;
    pk_perf_test.pp_getDateTable(r.pk_col, l_aaDummy);
    l_iProcedureTotal := l_iProcedureTotal + (SYSTIMESTAMP-l_tsStartTS);
    
    l_aaDummy.DELETE;
    l_tsStartTS := SYSTIMESTAMP;
    pk_perf_test.pp_getDateTable_NoCopy(r.pk_col, l_aaDummy);
    l_iNoCopyTotal := l_iNoCopyTotal + (SYSTIMESTAMP-l_tsStartTS);
  END LOOP;
  
  dbms_output.put_line('Total Cases: '||l_nCaseCount);
  dbms_output.put_line('Function Total: '||l_iFunctionTotal);
  dbms_output.put_line('Procedure Total: '||l_iProcedureTotal);
  dbms_output.put_line('No Copy Total: '||l_iNoCopyTotal);
END;
/
```

To which I received the following results:

```
Total Cases: 10787
Function Total: +00 00:00:22.857400
Procedure Total: +00 00:00:04.346413
No Copy Total: +00 00:00:01.942333
```

Now for my question.  I understand why `NOCOPY` is faster than the normal procedure.  What I don't understand is why is the regular procedure so much faster than the function?  Thinking it was a fluke, I ran it on multiple environments (multiple times) and received similar results (The result I posted is actually the average of all the runs).  Can anyone explain why the performance would be so different? Or point out a flaw in my test?

Comment: I don't think the procedure is faster. Oracle just read the results from cache. Try to execute them in different order. The bottleneck should be the SELECT statement anyway.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit You appear to be correct.  Reversing the order  garnered the following results. Function Total: +00 00:00:02.192932
Procedure Total: +00 00:00:07.502305
No Copy Total: +00 00:00:22.206270

Comment: When running performance comparisons between SQL and/or stored procedures/functions run `alter system flush shared pool;` before each, and run several iterations. This makes the runs start without buffered results form a prior access of the same or nearly the same data.    Note: Not a good idea in a Production environment.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25419629/409172 - tldr - there are some minor performance differences between procedures and functions depending on the PL/SQL optimization level, but that different shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked (if not many times). You can find a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942753/performance-difference-between-user-defined-function-and-stored-procedures), but to answer your question briefly:

**No, it does not affect performance. The only difference between functions and procedures is how they work. Use the one most fitting to your situation.**